# How to determine which server is the cause?

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup, dns-lookup

I have just registered a new domain with Malaysia NIC.  The registration system is not fully automatic and I am afraid that someone could have botched something in the setting up.  At the same time, my hosting company, 1and1, is also having some problems with the DNS features and they responded with "it's a known issue and no time scale to fix it".  It is a lost cause going to either of these two organizations to ask them to identify or localize the problem.

It has been quite a few days since the name was registered. If I use nslookup now I get "***No internal type for both IPV4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available"

The name servers for the domain name are supposedly correctly set to 1and1's name servers, according to Malaysia NIC's whois.  How can I trace the name lookup step by step, first to confirm whether the Malaysia NIC is correctly redirecting to the 1and1 name servers?

The domain name in question is 'artbug.com.my'.  If anyone can share with me what this name resolves to from his location, this would be much appreciated too.

Comment: There are a number of ways to trace the DNS delegation. `Dig` and `nslookup` are two of them. There are also a number of online DNS tools that can trace the DNS delegation. `http://www.simpledns.com/lookup-dg.aspx` is one of them. It would appear that your domain name has been correctly delegated to 1and1 but that 1and1 is having issues.

Comment: Thanks!  The simpledns.com website gives lots of step by step details I was seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Using the dig utility:

- dig -t ns artbug.com.my +trace
- dig some-A-record.artbug.com.my +trace

Will trace delegations from the root name servers to yours. It will also help to identify intermediate name servers to cycle queries against in case they are inconsistently incorrect.

I'm on my phone and don't currently have "dig" handy.

Comment: dig reports "connection timed out; no servers could be reached".  Which "servers" is this message referring to?  The one responsible for .my, .com.my, or the one for artbug.com.my?

Comment: thanks.  dig does not produce the same amount of diagnostics details as simpledns.com from joeqwerty above. It gives a simple "no servers could be reached".

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if a domain is actually registered by querying the whois server. For the Malaysia CC TLD domain that is http://whois.domainregistry.my

The registry confirms that your domain has indeed been registered (on September 24th).

The Whois will typically also show the domain servers that the domain has been registered on, in your case the following four:

```
ns-us.1and1-dns.com 217.160.82.2
ns-us.1and1-dns.us  217.160.81.2
ns-us.1and1-dns.de  217.160.80.2
ns-us.1and1-dns.org 217.160.83.2
```

As @Andy already explained you can then use `dig` to query the name-servers to check on the actual technical status of the domain. The +trace option shows that the registry has also completed their technical setup as well, as the records above can be found with the `dig +trace NS artbug.com.my` command.

When querying 1and1's nameservers all queries for your domain fail. They have not yet (at the time of writing) configured their DNS with your domain. At this point in time no "useful"  records (A, AAAA, MX records) are active for your domain.

You can only contact 1and1 tech support to get this resolved (or transfer the domain to a more supportive register and/or hosting company)

Comment: From what you see are you able to conclude that the Malaysian NIC has set things up properly?  I tried set type=ns and querying artbug.com.my in nslookup and I don't see the NS records.

Comment: Yesterday they were properly delegated to the 1&1 nameserrvers and those were not configered correctly, so a simple nslookup will fail

Comment: "properly delegated" - is your source of this info http://whois.domainregistry.my or do you have another source?  Thanks

Comment: Simply following the nameserver lookup trace  shows proper nameserver delegation from `[a-m].root-server.net` via the `.my` CC top level domain to above mentioned `ns-us.1and1-dns.[de|us|com|org]` nameservers, which still don't respond with anything for your domain.

Comment: Yes, it's crazy. I configured the IP addresses in the 1and1 Control Panel and clicked Save, and the four name servers worked for about a minute.  Then they all stopped resolving again.  1and1 has no clue what is going on. I can't even make them understand the problem.